# Showing a union of null sets is again a null set

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be any set and $\mathscr{F}$ a $\sigma-$algebra. Let $P$ be a probability on $\mathscr{F}$. We say $A \subset X$ is a null set of $P$ if we can find some $B \in \mathscr{F}$ with $A \subset B$ so that $P(B) = 0$

$\mathbf{Homework} $ $\mathbf{Exercise} : $ Please, carefully show that if given a sequence of null set $\{ A_n \}_{n \geq 1}$, then their union $A = \bigcup_{n \geq 1} A_n $ is also a null set.

$\mathbf{try}$: Since $A_n$ for all $n$ are null sets, then by definition we can pick sets $B_n$ so that $B_n \supset A_n$ so that $P(B_n) = 0$. We know

$$ A_n \subset B_n \; \; \forall \; n \implies \bigcup A_n \subset \bigcup B_n $$

and so by monotonicity of $P$, we have

$$ 0 \leq P \bigg( \bigcup A_n \bigg) \leq P \bigg( \bigcup B_n \bigg) = \sum P(B_n) = 0 $$

So we found a set $B = \bigcup B_n$ so that $A = \bigcup A_n \subset B $ and $P(B) = 0$ so by definition the union of null sets is again a null set.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: What allows you to say $P\left(\bigcup B_n\right) \le \sum P(B_n)$ but not $P\left(\bigcup A_n\right) \le \sum P(A_n)$?

Comment: should be equal because $P$ is probability. fixed it

Comment: But unless the sets are disjunct, their probabilities generally do *not* add up, so $\le$ is IMHO the right thing to use (although in hindsight we also know that $=$ is right, too, because the r.h.s. is $0$, and a probability cannot be negative). OTOH, I see nothing guaranteeing that $P(\bigcup A_n)$ actually exists ($P(A_n)$ quite obviously is allowed not to exist, or else the whole subset construction would not be needed). But I also don't see that you actually need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks good, but some details need to be corrected: First, the $A$'s don't necessarily belong to $\mathscr F$ so you don't want to (or need to) write $P(A_n)$ or $P(\bigcup A_n)$, since $P()$ may not be defined on the $A_n$. Second, the $B_n$ are not known to be disjoint, so you have to write
$$P(\bigcup B_n)\le\sum P(B_n)\quad,$$
which still allows you to reach the conclusion you want.

Finally, if you need to be really careful you will want to remark that each $B_n$ is a member of $\mathscr F$, therefore so is $\bigcup B_n$.